# What do we mean by the notation $\mathbf{x}_{p} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times\left(P^{2} \cdot C\right)}$?

Tags: deep-learning, papers, math, notation, vision-transformer

I was going through this VIT paper, what will it look like in torch , if we are trying to write this expression.

[image]

Comment: This itself isn't really an expression but a description of what $x_p$ looks like. Specifically, $x_p$ is a real-valued vector with the shape `[N, P^2 * C]`.
Of course, that data comes from your dataset, but as an example `torch.ones(N, P^2 * C, dtype=torch.float32)` will give you a vector with the same shape. Note that this will be a float32 vector, which makes it real-valued ($x_p \in \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @Chillston You could write that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Of course, sorry

Answer (score 2):

This itself isn't really an expression but a description of what $x_p$ looks like. Specifically, $x_p$ is a real-valued vector with the shape `[N, P^2 * C]`. Of course, that data comes from your dataset, but as an example

```
torch.ones(N, P^2 * C, dtype=torch.float32)

# an example output for values N=2, P=2, C=1
>>> [[1., 1., 1., 1.],
     [1., 1., 1., 1.]]
```

will give you a vector with the desired shape. Note that this will be a `float32` vector, which makes it real-valued ($x_p \in R$).